# Можно ли в GitHub выкладывать игру с авторскими правами на спрайты

Tags: python, github, pygame, лицензирование

Я разработал мини клон игры The Legend of Zelda: Link’s Awakening на pygame и хочу выложить её с открытым исходным кодом на GitHub в публичный репозиторий . Суть в том, что вся музыка и спрайты не мой, а принадлежат Nintendo. Я ведь могу выложить игру? В суд не подадут?

Comment: Обязательно подадут https://sun9-48.userapi.com/impg/nxFelRkwO86W8a9FbdspATQhHIX1sFoMQpcX5Q/qJYOMWYr4pQ.jpg?size=640x1014&quality=96&sign=8283a6a0786661bb0e936d4bf2ff6cf5&type=album

Comment: Скорее всего, все будет куда проще - аккаунт заблокируют, а репозитории удалят.

Comment: Хотя [Stabyourself](https://stabyourself.net/) каким-то чудом до сих пор не засудили за [Mari0](https://github.com/Stabyourself/mari0) и [Not Tetris 2](https://github.com/Stabyourself/nottetris2) 

Comment: Выходит единственный вариант чтобы выложить это всё самому сделать?